# Problem by configure JBoss EAP 6.x as Service on RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, jboss

I update my RHEL6 to RHEL7.7. But I must still use the Jboss EAP6.4.22 for a while. After the update of RHEL7 I have problem by starting the Jboss as a service. I've googled but till now haven't found any helpful information.

Here below is my situation and what I did:

After the installation of Jboss EAP 6 (RPM text installation), there is the file `/etc/init.d/jbossas`

I enable this as service with `chkconfig jbossas on`.
Then I create a file called `/usr/lib/systemd/system/eap6-jbossas-standalone.service` and it looks as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=JBoss EAP Systemctl script
After=NetworkManager.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jbossas start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/jbossas stop
PIDFile=/var/run/jbossas/jbossas-standalone.pid
```

I start the jboss with `systemctl start eap6-jbossas-standalone`. The jboss can be started but the cursor doesn't return. I have to use the ctrl+c to get the cursor.

Then I try to stop the jboss with 'systemctl stop eap6-jbossas-standalone' but the jboss can not be stopped. As I check its status with `systemctl status eap6-jbossas-standalone -l` I got following messages:
...

```
# systemctl status eap6-jbossas-standalone -l
● eap6-jbossas-standalone.service - JBoss EAP Systemctl script
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/eap6-jbossas-standalone.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Aug 28 10:04:59 s001ap21-test-n.ad001.proactiv.grp systemd[1]: Failed to start JBoss EAP Systemctl script.
Aug 28 10:04:59 s001ap21-test-n.ad001.proactiv.grp systemd[1]: Unit eap6-jbossas-standalone.service entered failed state.
Aug 28 10:04:59 s001ap21-test-n.ad001.proactiv.grp systemd[1]: eap6-jbossas-standalone.service failed.
Aug 28 10:15:24 s001ap21-test-n.ad001.proactiv.grp systemd[1]: Starting JBoss EAP Systemctl script...
Aug 28 10:15:24 s001ap21-test-n.ad001.proactiv.grp runuser[15400]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user jboss by (uid=0)
Aug 28 10:15:24 s001ap21-test-n.ad001.proactiv.grp runuser[15400]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user jboss
Aug 28 10:15:24 s001ap21-test-n.ad001.proactiv.grp runuser[15403]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user jboss by (uid=0)
Aug 28 10:15:24 s001ap21-test-n.ad001.proactiv.grp runuser[15403]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user jboss
Aug 28 10:15:24 s001ap21-test-n.ad001.proactiv.grp jbossas[15384]: Starting jbossas: runuser: warning: cannot change directory to /opt/rh/eap7/root/usr/share/wildfly: No such file or directory
Aug 28 10:15:52 s001ap21-test-n.ad001.proactiv.grp systemd[1]: Stopped JBoss EAP Systemctl script.
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Did you see the part that says “No such file or directory”?  Since you didn’t provide your init script, we can only guess but that’s why it is t working. Fix it.